# Symfony include_component()

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In Symfony I have a line `include_component('core', 'ohrmList');` that prints a table. But I am unable to find the for loop that generates the table.

I want some conditional formatting on the table. Should I go and edit in exact for loop or is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can read about components here **[Chapter 7 - Inside The View Layer](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_components)**

I think you must find module `core`, and in `templates` folder,file `_ohrmList.php`

Answer (score 2):

Components are like "little" controllers. Their goal is pretty much the same as partials' but you use components when you need to do some extra action which would normally not fit into the `view` layer (e.g. a database call, some complicated computations etc.).

You can find the functions of the components in your module's `actions` directory in the `components.class.php` file.

Each component renders a partial named after its' own name. So the `ohrmList` component will render the `_ohrmList.php` partial after running the `executeOhrmList()` function.

In your case you should look inside the `core` module.

Answer (score 2):

You can format component output based on values passed to it.

For example, you can render you view with

```
include_component('core', 'ohrmList', array('name' => 'Maria', 'status' => 'approved') )
```

and in _ohrmList.php you can do something like

```
<?php echo $name ?> - <?php if ( $status == 'approved' ): ?>congrats, you were approved!!!<?php endif; ?>
```